# How to fix dropping the box when adding a margin

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new with HTML and CSS. I have a homework. I have to create a responsive website as in first picture without using any CSS or JavaScript framework like Twitter Bootstrap. I should use only classes, div, paragraph. Writing width as pixels is not allowed.

[image: responsive-desktop](https://pasteboard.co/IF0YgwH.png)

But when I open the site I wrote, I see a page like this:

[image: no-margin](https://pasteboard.co/IF0XMtY.png)

When I add a line "margin: 5px;" in the style.css to the 43rd line I get this:

[image: with-margin](https://pasteboard.co/IF0Ytfw.png)

I realized that I have another issue to fix. The 7th column named "Alt Başlık 7" is so higher than it should be. If anyone help with that too, I would be appreciated.

I uploaded my codes because they are so long to write here. So there is the [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ja3vGya2XSpY3RLJq53HMerHQuHKtLEr)

I need at least 10 but have only 1 reputation so I linked the images. Sorry about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: In the text editor you can click on the icon that looks like this [<>].A popup will appear where you can add your code, and allow people to see it working. If you don't have privileges yet to do that, you can paste in your code in to the text editor, highlight it, and then click on the icon that looks like this { }. That will make your code more readable.

Comment: Thank you both. I will be more careful from now about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together an example of using padding instead to achieve what you want. Instead of adding the border styling to the column, I have added it to a div that is inside the column.

The code below doesn't allow you to define column count based on screen size. It is just a simple example to show how you would achieve what.

It is important to understand this floating method of grid layouts, but I would also recommend looking in to Flexbox.

**Note:** After clicking the blue [Run code snippet] button below the code, click on the [Full Screen] button to see the responsiveness.

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
.row {
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;
}
.col-inner {
 border:2px solid #000;
 padding:10px;
}
.col {
  float:left;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.col-12, .col-6 {
  width:100%;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .col-6 {
   width:50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-6">
  <div class="col-inner">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus sem, eleifend sit amet finibus sit amet, laoreet ac nibh. Phasellus vulputate nisl finibus odio molestie laoreet. Donec ac efficitur elit. Donec blandit arcu mollis tincidunt luctus. Morbi sed lectus porta felis interdum tincidunt. Cras sed est turpis. Nunc sollicitudin porttitor euismod.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col col-6">
  <div class="col-inner">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus sem, eleifend sit amet finibus sit amet, laoreet ac nibh. Phasellus vulputate nisl finibus odio molestie laoreet. Donec ac efficitur elit. Donec blandit arcu mollis tincidunt luctus. Morbi sed lectus porta felis interdum tincidunt. Cras sed est turpis. Nunc sollicitudin porttitor euismod.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col col-6">
  <div class="col-inner">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus sem, eleifend sit amet finibus sit amet, laoreet ac nibh. Phasellus vulputate nisl finibus odio molestie laoreet. Donec ac efficitur elit. Donec blandit arcu mollis tincidunt luctus. Morbi sed lectus porta felis interdum tincidunt. Cras sed est turpis. Nunc sollicitudin porttitor euismod.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col col-6">
  <div class="col-inner">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus sem, eleifend sit amet finibus sit amet, laoreet ac nibh. Phasellus vulputate nisl finibus odio molestie laoreet. Donec ac efficitur elit. Donec blandit arcu mollis tincidunt luctus. Morbi sed lectus porta felis interdum tincidunt. Cras sed est turpis. Nunc sollicitudin porttitor euismod.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col col-12">
  <div class="col-inner">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus sem, eleifend sit amet finibus sit amet, laoreet ac nibh. Phasellus vulputate nisl finibus odio molestie laoreet. Donec ac efficitur elit. Donec blandit arcu mollis tincidunt luctus. Morbi sed lectus porta felis interdum tincidunt. Cras sed est turpis. Nunc sollicitudin porttitor euismod.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is clear and worked but when I try to center the last column it still starts from the top of the screen. And margin between box above disappears. Tried write something but still couldn't succeed that.